# how i can hide past dates in datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I want to disable past dates and show a text message "you can not select past date" in datepicker calendar by using ({ minDate: 0}) but i am unable to understand how i can use this in my existing code.

Here is my code:

```js
<script>
var form, colourField;

$(function() {
  $( "#datepicker-13" ).datepicker({onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
  
  
  ({ minDate: 0})

var mySplitResult;

mySplitResult = dateText.split("/");
for(i = 2; i < mySplitResult.length; i++)
           {

           }
mySplitResult[2] = (mySplitResult[2] % 100 == 0) ? (mySplitResult[2] % 400 === 0) : (mySplitResult[2] % 4 === 0);


if(mySplitResult[2]== true){
 
showDiv();

}
else{
 showDiv(); 
 }
   
    }
  })

});

 </script>
 
 <script>
    function showDiv() {
   document.getElementById('welcomeDiv').style.display = "block";
}

    </script>
```

your thoughts and suggestion will be appreciated.Thanks in advance.

Comment: You really didn't bother to read the documentation at all? -> https://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/1svb6dmp/

Comment: your recommendation is not working.

Comment: Seems to work just fine -> https://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/1svb6dmp/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(function() {
  $( "#datepicker-13" ).datepicker({
   
   onSelect: function(dateText, inst) 
   {
  
  
var mySplitResult;

mySplitResult = dateText.split("/");
for(i = 2; i < mySplitResult.length; i++)
           
mySplitResult[2] = (mySplitResult[2] % 100 == 0) ? (mySplitResult[2] % 400 === 0) : (mySplitResult[2] % 4 === 0);


if(mySplitResult[2]== true){
 
showDiv();

}
else{
 showDiv(); 
 }
       },minDate: 0
  }) 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $( ".datepicker" ).datepicker({
       dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
       defaultDate: +0,
       onSelect:{your thing},
       minDate: new Date(),
      });
```

I would prefer doing something like this , every thing is in the jquery documentation.

[Min-Max](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#min-max) attribute in jquery datepicker.Check this out.